# Ruby Rails rake db migrate not working or schema file not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I created a new table on schema.rb
here is the new code line i put:

```
  create_table "book", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer   "count"
  end
```

but after when i run rake db:migrate command schema.rb turns into old file, when i open it my new create_table code just gone any ideas? im new to ruby rails Thanks!

i tried this too:

```
rake db:drop:all
rake db:create:all
rake db:migrate
```

but still schema.rb file not updating into new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `schema.rb` file is generated, and any change you make in it will go away the next time it's generated. The normal way to make database changes in Rails is with [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

Answer (score 0):

Never edit your `schema.rb` directly.
`schema.rb` is auto-generated from the current state of the database.

You should create a migration file for doing this.

Read ***[Active Record Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)***.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a migration rather than modifying the schema directly.  You should NEVER modify the schema.rb file directly, since the next time you migrate, it will be overwritten.  Rails generates the schema file.  Try the following in the terminal:

```
rails generate model Book user_id:integer title:text count:integer
```

and then run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

This should fix your issues. You are now allowing rails to make the model for you (this generates a migration to make the new model), and then migrating it changes the database tables.  Take a look at your `schema.rb` file afterwords, and it should look correct.

For more info on model generators, take a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#model-generators).